# Razor and conditional values in properties

Tags: razor

Ok, here's what I want to do. I want to adjust the available max length in a TextBox.

What I currently have is this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BrowserTitle, new { @class = "form-control txtBrowserTitle", @id = "txtBrowserTitle", @maxlength = (70 - Model.ShortName.Length) })
```

Where m is my ViewModel (the @model on the .cshtml page).
So BrowserTitle is the "Title" I want to appear as the browser title (like you see in the tabs).

But what I need to do is the following:

If my Model.ShortName.Length is 0 (i.e. it's an empty string), I want to use Model.StandardName.Length.

I found some thing *similar* to what I'm trying to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757782/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-razor-view)

But that's not quite what I'm looking for. I need to be able to use either the ?: operator, or the ?? operator *inline* for the @maxlength parameter.

Forgive my ignorance, as I'm still new to Razor.

Comment: Not clear what you wanting. You are saying that if `Model.ShortName.Length is 0` you want to use that value. Does that mean you want the value of `maxlength` to `70`? And if `Length` is say `10`, would you then want `maxlength`to be `60`? And what do you mean by _I want to appear as the browser title_?

Comment: Why cant you use the ?? or ?: operator?

Comment: @StephenMuecke what I want is if Model.ShortName.Length is zero, to use the *other* value (i.e. Model.StandardName.Length. The max length of the field is 70. So if  Model.ShortName is XYZ then that would leave me 66 characters to play with. But if Model.ShortName has a length of 0, and Model.StandardName is XYZ, Incorporated, that length is 17, which would leave me with 52 characters.

Comment: @Tobias I don't quite know how to use it in Razor. But I'm going to try and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: The just add `@{ var max = Model.ShortName.Length == 0 ? Model.StandardName.Length : 70 - Model.ShortName.Length; }` and then `@Html.TextBoxFor( ...., new { @class = "...", maxlength = max })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the great response! Just what I needed. I upvoted your previous comment, but I want to make sure you get proper credit.

Comment: Your 'self' answer is not an answer and will be deleted by the community. If you want to add an answer, then show the code that solves your problem